# Unable to use $http.post() from mobile, but working fine from browser

Tags: angularjs, cordova, rest, post, http-status-code-403

Currently I'm developing hybrid app using Ionic where I'm trying to post some request in DB through rest api. Where it is working fine from desktop browser(ionic serve) but same code when I deploy to mobile, I'm getting 403. I'm currently using AngularJS $http.post() method to do so.

```
var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }
var data = {"test":"someData"};
$http.post('url',data,config)
                .success(function (data, status) {
                    //
                })
                .error(function (data, status) {
                    //getting 403 when deploy the code in android
                });
```

Comment: May be a duplicate... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385301/cant-perform-post-request-in-android-browser-with-angularjs

Comment: Which version of ionic are you using? There could be 2 probable causes. One mentioned by @sourdoughdetzel above and another related to `cordova-plugin-whitelist`.

Comment: I tried the 
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
but not luck. And about Cordova Whitelist, if it doesn't work then it should not work from browser as well I think. But it is working from browser but not from mobile!