# Getting 403 errror while accessing apache restful services from mobile

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, restful-authentication

I am getting 403 error for POST request when restful services which are deployed on tomcat server are accessed from mobile device, from desktop we are getting proper response, below is the error in access logs

"POST /myservice/check HTTP/1.1" 403 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1"

Please let me know what is the reason for this

Regards
Pallavi

Comment: 403 refers to access forbidden messages

Comment: Can you share your post request

Comment: It's normal Angular js post request which works absolutely fine in local desktop only from mobile its getting 403

Comment: Can you look into this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385301/cant-perform-post-request-in-android-browser-with-angularjs